# "virsh list" command not showing VM created by "qemu-system-x86_64" command

Tags: kvm, virsh

I created a VM using "qemu-system-x86_64" command. The VM is up and running. I can access it and list it by command "ps -ef | grep qemu-system-x86_64.

But if I try to list the VM using "virsh list" command then I do not see it there.  Could you please point me what could be the reason?

Why is "virsh list" command not able to list VMs created by "qemu-system" command? I thought that virsh is an application that uses libvirt to access KVM/linux's virtualization capabilities. So even if VM is created by any method, then also virsh should be able to query KVM to check the already running VMs on the host.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`qemu-system-x86_64` is a `backend` used by `virsh` to start a `VM`. Although `qemu-system-x86_64` is libvirt-dependent, it does not register any running instances inside `virsh`/`libvirtd` metadata.